# Ion thrusters' efficiency and the Grid potentials

Tags: electric-fields, charge, potential, propulsion

In ion thrusters, the ions' exhaust velocity depends on the potential difference between the 2 grids as shown in the diagram.
[image]

Since, the maximum potential difference between the grids is only bounded by Cold electron emission (since space is a vacuum) and I think that we didn't even get close to that value.. Then why cant we just raise the potential difference higher. Would there be any change in the efficiency of the engine? For example, would there be problems with ions bombarding the negative grid?
(I think not) But I am interested in stuff close to that. Would there be an increase or decrease in the efficiency of an ion thruster if there exists a higher potential difference between the grids and why?

Comment: You need to make the potential. You need to hold off that potential (both grids are still connected to the spacecraft!). Yes, you worry about the ions hitting the grid. And other engineering issues...

Comment: what do you mean by holding off that potential, maintaining it? Can you elaborate on this?